# Finding an angle having the adjacent and incline % of hypotenuse?

Tags: trigonometry

Equation- ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRqoj.jpg)

I understand SOHCAHTOA but now confused with only being given the 4% incline of the hypotenuse. What formula would you use in the attached equation?

Thanks so much

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Could you provide some more information as to how the 4% could be understood? Does it mean that the line gains 4% in height per every unit? And is the representation true to scale?

Answer (score 0):

The 4% incline means that for every 100 units along the horizontal, it will rise 4 units vertically. You have the height as 1380 so that means you can set up a ratio to find X then use tangent to find the angle Y.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by setting up a ratio to find X?

Comment: You will setup a ratio as 4/100=1380/x, then you can cross-multiply and solve for X.